# How to deserialize a missing json field as null?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "a": "foo",
    "b": {
        "c": "bar"
    }
}
```

Sometimes, the `b` field is absent, like this:

```
{
    "a": "foo"
}
```

Here is the class I'm deserializing this JSON into:

```
public class MyObj
{
    private string _a;
    private MyType _b = new MyType();

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("a", 
    Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public string A {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("b",
    Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull,
    NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public MyType B {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; }
    }
}
```

Current behavior when a missing `b` field is encountered in JSON is that it simply fills it in with a `new MyType()` object.  I'd like `_b` to be set to `null` when `b` is missing from the JSON.

I can't seem to figure it out though... there must be a way to do this.  Help!

Comment: `private MyType _b = new MyType();` this is creating your `_b`. Remove it.

Comment: I'm an idiot - thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:  Simply replacing
`private MyType _b = new MyType()` with `private MyType;` solves this issue.

How embarassing